# Delete Items from JSON-File - Python

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I have a JSON file and would like to remove the beginning and end part

```
{
 "records":
    [{
         "id":"53c5d162-3dd4-41ea-afd1-378b5be1bf04",
         "userid":"u111124027",
         "username":"Testuser",
         "deviceid":"1185494411",
         "devicename":"",
         "start_date":"2020-05-19T06:46:55Z",
         "fee":0.0,
         "currency":"None",
         "billing_state":"Bill",
         "contact_id":"c410618636"
       }], 
"records_remaining":0
}
```

Parts to remove

```
{
"records": , 
"records_remaining":0
}
```

Code to remove the part

```
for element in data:
    if 'records' in element:
        del element['records']
```

Error:

```
del element['records']
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion
```

If I remove the parts manually, I can manipulate the JSON via

```
if 'userid' in element:
    del element['userid']
```

Is there a possibility to remove the two parts?
I address a rest API and save the -get into a JSON-File.
To continue working with the JSON-file, I have to remove these two parts

At the end the json-file should look like this:

```
[{
    "id":"53c5d162-3dd4-41ea-afd1-378b5be1bf04",
    "userid":"u111124027",
    "username":"Testuser",
    "deviceid":"1185494411",
    "devicename":"",
    "start_date":"2020-05-19T06:46:55Z",
    "fee":0.0,
    "currency":"None",
    "billing_state":"Bill",
    "contact_id":"c410618636"
}]
```

Comment: It looks that, rather than removing the keys, you want to extract the value: `data["records"]`

Answer (score 2):

It’s pretty easy to load a JSON object in Python. Python has a built-in package called json, which can be used to work with JSON data. It’s done by using the json module, which provides us with a lot of methods which among loads() and load() methods are gonna help us to read the JSON file.

> Deserialization of JSON

The Deserialization of JSON means the conversion of JSON objects into their respective Python objects. The load()/loads() method is used for it. If you have used JSON data from another program or obtained as a string format of JSON, then it can easily be deserialized with load()/loads(), which is usually used to load from string, otherwise the root object is in list or dict.

**json.load()**: **json.load() accepts file object, parses the JSON data, populates a Python dictionary with the data and returns it back to you.**

Syntax:

```
json.loads(file object)
```

Normal reading from json would be -

```
# Python program to read 
# json file 


import json 

# Opening JSON file 
f = open('data.json',) 

# returns JSON object as  
# a dictionary 
data = json.load(f) 

# saving the records array
records = data["records"]

# Iterating through the json 
# list from records array
for i in data['records']: 
    print(i) 

# Closing file 
f.close()
```

Now according to your use case, you just need the records and no other keys from json. rather than removing it from json, you can just access it with `data["records"]` that would solve the issue.

However, if you still want to remove it then you can use `data["records"]` from json and store it in a variable. You will then have to write that into the file for persistence.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, I learned something new.

Now I can continue working with the file and convert it into a CSV.

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(records, f)

df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```